# Loading data from JSON into Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: json, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have recently pulled multiple JSON files from a SQL database and I would like to load them into my Google Datastore. Can anyone suggest the best way to go about this. I have read the docs and  they detail how to create entities but I cannot determine how to do a bulk data load. Any tips or tricks would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Two years later and no answer! The key to doing this right now, in 2017, seems to be the new [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) thing in Google Cloud. There are SDKs for both Java and Python, but it's still so new I'm using the [Java SDK, the 1.9 version](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK). I've adapted two of the examples and have it putting data into the Datastore. It seems to play nice with namespaces so far, but it's a little difficult to make fields with parent/child relationships.

Comment: Did you manage a good way to do this. I've got my sql tables in key value format in json but my dataflow job says there is problem in json but jsonlint says it is valid json. Dont know where to go.. lol

Comment: @Prany i did not find anything other than this but since then the `gcloud` CLI has added more to interact with datastore. Maybe check out the docs on `gcloud datastore import`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to find some more info on this